# Allow end user to modify recurring paypal subscription amount

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing, recurring

I've read a few responses here regarding the modification of the recurring fee amount but still confused.

We have 5 subscriptions levels per month:
£10 
£15 
£20
£30 
£50

We want to be able to let customers change their subscription package to any of the other options.

It sounds like if they are changing to a package with more than 20% difference from the one they are on - we would have to make them cancel and start a new subscription.

Surely there is a way to have the subscriber confirm they are happy to change the amount?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User can modify your paypal amount, but some restriction are there.

In Standard account, you can use "modify" html variable to change subscription amount as below.

0 – allows subscribers only to sign up for new subscriptions
1 – allows subscribers to sign up for new subscriptions and modify their current subscriptions
2 – allows subscribers to modify only their current subscriptions
The default value is 0.

Following link will hel you more,
https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_subscribe_buttons#id08ADF500NXK

you can not modify often your amount, you can only increase the subscription amount by 20% for 180 days.

but if you move to paypal payflow($30/month), paypal itself provide API to communicate with paypal service. its very flexible to modify, cancel subscription.

paypal standard - user cannot cancel subscription their self if they dont have paypal login.
paypal payflow - user can able to cancel their subscription.

Comment: They've changed the design or something and the link that you provide is outdated and wrong.