# PayPal related programming in PHP with ref to recurring(subscription) payments

Tags: php, paypal

In normal PayPal flow, for one time payments, first we try to authorize the payment request, and then the next step is to complete the authorisation request.

As per PayPal docs, for recurring(subscription) payments the docs mention that first we have to authorize as usual, after that we have to set up the subscription agreement.

These are my questions-- If you can point me to the relevant APIs (if applicable) that would be great(for points 3 and 4 esp.)

1. In normal flow, the details of the item(s) being purchased are sent with the authorisation request-- do I do the same for the subscription as well?
2. Do I send the user to the subscription agreement request after the initial authorisation (i.e. first step--> authorise, second step--> complete authorise) are complete? Or do I do this in place of the second step (ie in place of "Complete Authorise")?
3. Can I modify an existing subscription agreement- both in terms of changing the amount, as well as changing the description for that subscription agreement?
4. Can I change only the description for the next recurring amount in an existing subscription?

Comment: Hope it may help you,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810792/allow-end-user-to-modify-recurring-paypal-subscription-amount?answertab=votes#tab-top